# Pass params from one component to another with react

Tags: react-router

I am developing this app , and I am stuck . So I will try to explain what I am doing .

I have only 2 pages right now, that will show 2 different tables ( with datatable from material-ui).
This 2 tables comes from an API that I need to fetch on both component.

On the first page, I need to click on any cell from the first row, and then I will be redirect to another page, that will fetch a different endpoint and it's response will be on this new table. But this second page depends on the first page, and I need to pass the value from the cell that I clicked to this other component.

It's something like this : the first page will fetch this endpoint "www.blablabla.com/teams" and the table will come with id, name of teams and description
and the second page will fetch this endpoint "www.blablabla.com/teams/name/components" , and the table will come with id, name of the team, projects, and other things
This parameter "name" is the string value that I clicked on a cell from the first page

In my first component, I have this , let's call it Teams.jsx:

const columns = [
{ field:"name", headerName:"Name", renderCell: (params) => <Link to ={'team/${params.value}/components'}>{params.value}
...

On my second component , that is called Component.jsx , I need to pass that "params.value" to this line:

fetch("www.blablabla.com/teams/name/components")

like I mentioned before, that "params.value" needs to substitute this parameter "name" on the endpoint

And one last thing... on my main App.js , I have to define my Route to this second component, that is something like this right now:

and again, this name needs to be replaced by that "params.value"

Right now I know that one of the teams is called "team_rocket" , so I used an endpoint that points to this team , like "team/team_rocket/component, so if I click on this team on the first page, I will be redirect to the page that I want, but like I said , I need that the parameter comes from the first component
I really just need to pass the value from the cell that I clicked to the URL on the second component

If someone knows how to help , I will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the name as a query to the second page

```js
import { ..., useLocation } from "react-router-dom"

function useQuery() {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search);
}

function MainApp() {
  let query = useQuery();

  return (
    <>
      <Component1>
       <table>
         <cell link to=`/teams?name=${params.value}` />
       </table>
      </Component1>
      <Component2 name={query.get("name")} />
    </>
  );
}

function Component2({ name }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <table>
       <cell value={name}/>
       ....
      </table
    </div>
  );
}
```

`URLSearchParams` is a web api -> [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

for more info router query, refer the [doc](https://reactrouter.com/web/example/query-parameters)